# TypeError: FUNCTION NAME () missing 1 required positional argument: 'v_air

Tags: python, function, attributes, numpy-ndarray

I have two problems:

1. When I call the functiuon Python says that I miss one positional argument of the function **simplified_friction_method** but all the arguments are written above.

If your str() or list() objects might end up being empty as so: astr = '' or alist = [], then you might want to use alist[-1:] instead of alist[-1] for object "sameness".

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3]
some_list[-1] = 5 # Set the last element
some_list[-2] = 3 # Set the second to last element
some_list
a_list = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three']
a_list[-1]
'three'
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. You seem to be calling the function with the correct number of arguments in the last line you showed, so the error may be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: `TypeError: simplified_friction_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v_air` I would guess this is because you defined the function outside the `Duct` class. Once you pass an additional argument, the first argument you pass `duct_circ.V_dot`, which is a `np.ndarray` is passed as self, and thus you get `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rho_air'`

Comment: Is `simplified_friction_method` inside the class that `EN` is an instance of?

Comment: EN is the Engine another file and I call the file that has all the function in this way:                                       
 import ENGINE as EN

Comment: Please show a [mre], which includes the context of the definition of `simplified_friction_method`.

Comment: Maybe they made `simplified_friction_method` static by accident?

Comment: @mapf I do not know what do you mean with static, so the only way is to define the attributes in class, also all the other input?

Comment: Don't worry, I was wrong. But now that you have changed the definition of your `simplified_friction_method` I think you shouldn't run into any more problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, you basically already had it right but just for the record, here is the working code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root


def viscosity(Tair_inlet):
    mu=(1.458*(10**-6)*(Tair_inlet+ 273.15)**1.5)/((Tair_inlet+ 273.15)+110.4)
    return mu

def per_circ(D_1):
    p_c = np.pi*(D_1)
    return p_c

def Tair_outlet(Ts_int,Tair_inlet, hint, p_c, v_air, rho_air, cp_air, L ):
    k = hint/(p_c*v_air*rho_air*cp_air)
    Tair_outlet = Ts_int + (Tair_inlet-Ts_int)*np.exp(-k*L)
    return Tair_outlet

def simplified_friction_method(V_dot, rho_air , L, mu, delta_P, v_air, epsilon ):
    m_dot = V_dot * rho_air
    print('m_dot',m_dot, '[kgs^-1]')
    D_0 = (4*m_dot/(np.pi*rho_air*v_air))**(1/2)
    D_1 = D_0
    print('D_0',D_0, '[m]')
    Re  = (v_air * D_0 * rho_air) / mu
    print('Re', Re )
    f_0= 0*D_0
    f_0 = (-2*np.log((epsilon/D_0)/3.7065))**-2
    print('f_0', f_0,)
    delta_P_tot = delta_P*L
    f_1 = f_0
    f_2 = 0
    e =np.ones(D_0.size)
    print("e",e)
    while e.any() > 0.0001:
        D_1 = ((f_1 * L)/delta_P_tot )* rho_air *(v_air)**2
        print('D_1', D_1, '[m]')
        Re  = (v_air * D_1 * rho_air) / mu
        f_2=(-2*abs(np.log((epsilon/D_1)/3.7065 + 2.5226/(Re*np.sqrt(f_1)))))**-2
        e = abs(f_1-f_2)
        print('e', e, )
        f_1 = f_2 
    return('D_1', D_1,'Re', Re,'f', f_2,'e', e )


class Duct:
    def __init__(
        self, Tair_inlet, Ts_int, hint, cp_air, rho_air, Rstar, epsilon
    ):
        self.Tair_inlet = Tair_inlet
        self.Ts_int = Ts_int
        self.hint = hint
        self.cp_air = cp_air
        self.rho_air = rho_air
        self.Rstar = Rstar
        self.epsilon = epsilon


duct_ret = Duct(18, 19.5, 3, 1010, 1.2, 8324.68/29, 0.2/1000)
duct_circ = Duct(18, 19.5, 3, 1010, 1.2, 8324.68/29, 0.2/1000)

duct_ret.L = 8
duct_circ.L = np.array([[10, 8, 10, 8]])
duct_circ.V_dot = np.array([[3, 1, 2, 1]])     
duct_circ.v_air = np.array([[5, 3, 5, 3]])
duct_circ.deltaP = 1

duct_circ.mu = viscosity(duct_circ.Tair_inlet)
print(duct_circ.mu)

duct_circ.D_1 = simplified_friction_method(
    duct_circ.rho_air, duct_circ.V_dot, duct_circ.L, duct_circ.mu,
    duct_circ.deltaP, duct_circ.v_air, duct_circ.epsilon
)

print(duct_circ.D_1)
```

Note that since I don't have two files, I don't import `EN` and thus removed the `EN.` in front of the function call. I also added the `epsilon` parameter to the `Duct` class which was missing in your version and passed it to the `simplified_friction_method` function. There are many ways how you could improve the code, but for now I think it's more important that it works and you understand it. You obviously don't really know how Classes work, so I would suggest you [look into that](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp).